# Save generic complex property as a serialized column using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization

If I have a model like below, how can I save it to the database so that the generic complex property is represented as a single text column?

```
public class Tracker<T> : BaseModel where T : BaseModel
{
    public T Model { get; set; }
}
```

I've seen examples with non-generic complex types but none with generic types.

Comment: Can you post the non generic examples?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want a complex (non-scalar) type stored in a single column you need to provide a custom conversion of the .NET type to a storage type and format (eg serialize the object to a string and store in an NVarchar(max) column).

In EF 6 you do this with a [NotMapped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) property that reads and writes to a mapped string property.

In EF Core you can avoid having two properties by using [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions).

Comment: Interestingly, when using value conversion (example below), EF core still create a table in database during `OnModelCreating`:

modelBuilder.Entity(entity.Name).Property<Money>' (property.Name).HasConversion(
                            x => $"{x.Currency} {x.Amount}",
                            x => MoneyParser.Parse(x));